# require_once Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, moodle

I'm baffled by this - it works if I restart the web server but then will fail again. I've tried it on 2 different servers

PHP 5.5.3 with Apache 2.4.6

PHP 5.5.9 with nginx 1.4.6

```
require_once('myclass.php');
class mynewclass extends myclass {
    // Fatal error: Class 'myclass' not found in ...
}
```

But if I try this I get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class myclass` in ...

```
require_once('myclass.php');
if (!class_exists('myclass')) {
    require('myclass.php');
    // Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class myclass` in ...
}
class mynewclass extends myclass {

}
```

Comment: what's the content of `myclass.php` file ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll wager you're defining myclass in a namespace:

```
namespace foo;
class myclass {}
```

And then trying to reference it outside that namespace;

```
class mynewclass extends myclass {}
// PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myclass' not found in...
```

You'll need to either put the second class in the same namespace:

```
namespace foo;
class mynewclass extends myclass {}
```

Or `use` the namespace:

```
use \foo\myclass;
class mynewclass extends myclass {}
```

Or specify the full namespace name in your reference:

```
class mynewclass extends \foo\myclass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
    //require_once('myclass.php');//remove this line

    if (!class_exists('myclass')) {
        require('myclass.php');
        // then if class not exists it will be included.
    }
```